# BigDecimal arithmetic on JSF pages

Tags: jsf, bigdecimal, jsf-2.2

For example, given below a JSF managed bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class Bean implements Serializable {

    private BigDecimal price; //Getter only.
    private BigDecimal currencyRate; //Getter only.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        price=new BigDecimal(5678);
        currencyRate=new BigDecimal(0.016622);
    }
}
```

Multiplication of `price` and `currencyRate` can be displayed on `<h:outputText>`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.price * bean.currencyRate}"/>
```

Does this multiplication yield `BigDecimal` or it is simply a `double` value?

---

In other words, is this equivalent to the following?

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.price.multiply(bean.currencyRate)}"/>
```

It displays `94.3797160000000077070825277303356415359303355216979980468750` in both the cases.

---

And what if when there is a converter to display a specified number of decimal digits, two for example as follows?

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.price * bean.currencyRate}"
              converter="#{bigDecimalConverter}"/>
```

I want the result of such expressions to be `BigDecimal` anyway.

Comment: BigDecimal surely, but it's easy enough to test for yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to test for a type on JSF pages. The result is same in both the cases - `94.3797160000000077070825277303356415359303355216979980468750`.

Comment: You *have* just tested *and* verified it. If it was double you wouldn't get all that precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [El 3.0 spec pdf](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html) (page 13 - section 1.7.1):

> The evaluation of arithmetic operators is described in the following sections. A and B
>   are the evaluation of subexpressions.
>
> **1.7.1 Binary operators - A {+,-,*} B**
>
> - If A and B are `null`, return `(Long)0`
> - If A or B is a `BigDecimal`, coerce both to `BigDecimal` and then:
>
>   - If operator is +, return `A.add(B)`
>   - If operator is -, return `A.subtract(B)`
>   - If operator is *, return `A.multiply(B)`
> - If A or B is a `Float`, `Double`, or `String` containing ., e, or E:
>
>   - If A or B is `BigInteger`, coerce both A and B to `BigDecimal` and apply 
>       operator.
>   - Otherwise, coerce both A and B to `Double` and apply operator
> - If A or B is `BigInteger`, coerce both to `BigInteger` and then:
>
>   - If operator is +, return `A.add(B)`
>   - If operator is -, return `A.subtract(B)`
>   - If operator is *, return `A.multiply(B)`
> - Otherwise coerce both A and B to `Long` and apply operator
> - If operator results in exception, error

Therefore, yes the EL expression `#{bean.price * bean.currencyRate}"` as specified in `<h:outputText>`,

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.price * bean.currencyRate}"/>
```

is evaluated to a `java.math.BigDecimal`, since both `bean.price` and `bean.currencyRate` in the corresponding backing bean are of type `java.math.BigDecimal` - `bean.price.multiply(bean.currencyRate)` is performed internally.